# How do I get back to a current state after accidentally rebasing HEAD^100?

Tags: git, git-rebase

After accidentally doing a `git rebase -i` back 100, my repo is in a state that is thousands of commits behind upstream, and three ahead (my three actual commits).

The "lazy" way I solved this was to create a new branch from upstream and then `git cherry-pick` my 3 commits into it.

I know there must be a "right" way to fix the problem that doesn't involve creating a new branch and deleting the old one.

I tried `git rebase upstream/master` but there were many many many merge conflicts in files that I hadn't touched. Why?

Comment: Why do you assume your solution was bad? I would have done that too. Straight to the point. (Going to your `reflog` would have been an alternative.)

Comment: `HEAD^100` should almost certainly have just produced an error message and been rejected: a merge commit with 100 parents is unheard-of (though [the Linux repository does have one monster "cthulhu merge" with 66 parents](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/blog/2017/the-biggest-and-weirdest-commits-in-linux-kernel-git-history)).

Comment: @torek Yes, I also assumed he meant `HEAD~100`